# Merge dataframes by groups common to both

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

I have two datasets of lobster egg size data taken by different samplers, which will be used to assess measurement variability. Each sampler measures ~50 eggs\lobster from numerous lobster. However, occasionally some lobsters are processed by sampler one and not sampler two, and vice versa. I would like to combine the data from the two samplers as a new dataset, but remove all data from lobsters processed only by one sampler. I've played around with dplyr with semi_join and intersect, but I need the matching to be preformed between dataset 1 -> 2 and 2 <-1. I am able to create a new dataset which binds rows from the two samplers but not clear on how to remove all the unique lobster IDs between the two datasets in the new one.

Here is a simplified version of my data where there are multiple egg area measurements taken from multiple lobster, but the sampling does not always overlap (i.e., eggs measured from an individual only by one sampler and not the other):

```
install.packages(dplyr)
library(dplyr)

sampler1 <- data.frame(LobsterID=c("Lobster1","Lobster1","Lobster2",
                                   "Lobster2","Lobster2","Lobster2",
                                   "Lobster2","Lobster3","Lobster3","Lobster3"),
                       Area=c(.4,.35,1.1,1.04,1.14,1.1,1.05,1.7,1.63,1.8),
                       Sampler=c(rep("Sampler1", 10)))
sampler2 <- data.frame(LobsterID=c("Lobster1","Lobster1","Lobster1",
                                   "Lobster1","Lobster1","Lobster2",
                                   "Lobster2","Lobster2","Lobster4","Lobster4"),
                       Area=c(.41,.44,.47,.43,.38,1.14,1.11,1.09,1.41,1.4),
                       Sampler=c(rep("Sampler2", 10)))

combined <- bind_rows(sampler1, sampler2)

desiredresult <- combined[-c(8, 9, 10, 19, 20), ]
```

The bottom line of the script is the desired result from the mock data. I was hoping to limit use to base R or dplyr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sampler1 %>% rbind(sampler2) %>% filter(LobsterID %in% intersect(sampler1$LobsterID, sampler2$LobsterID))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
combined <- bind_rows(sampler1, sampler2)


Lobsters.2.sample <- as.character(unique(sampler1$LobsterID)[unique(sampler1$LobsterID) %in% unique(sampler2$LobsterID)])

combined <- combined[combined$LobsterID %in% Lobsters.2.sample,]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base `R`

```
combined <-rbind(sampler1, sampler2)
inBoth <- intersect(sampler1[["LobsterID"]], sampler2[["LobsterID"]])
output <- combined[combined[["LobsterID"]] %in% inBoth, ]
```

`intersect` finds the set union of two vectors, giving you the lobsters in both samples.  All functions are vectorized, so it should run pretty fast.

Answer (score 1):

Bind the rows, group, and filter by the number of distinct samplers in each group:

```
sampler1 %>% bind_rows(sampler2) %>% 
    group_by(LobsterID) %>% 
    filter(n_distinct(Sampler) == 2)

## Source: local data frame [15 x 3]
## Groups: LobsterID [2]
## 
##    LobsterID  Area  Sampler
##        <chr> <dbl>    <chr>
## 1   Lobster1  0.40 Sampler1
## 2   Lobster1  0.35 Sampler1
## 3   Lobster2  1.10 Sampler1
## 4   Lobster2  1.04 Sampler1
## 5   Lobster2  1.14 Sampler1
## 6   Lobster2  1.10 Sampler1
## 7   Lobster2  1.05 Sampler1
## 8   Lobster1  0.41 Sampler2
## 9   Lobster1  0.44 Sampler2
## 10  Lobster1  0.47 Sampler2
## 11  Lobster1  0.43 Sampler2
## 12  Lobster1  0.38 Sampler2
## 13  Lobster2  1.14 Sampler2
## 14  Lobster2  1.11 Sampler2
## 15  Lobster2  1.09 Sampler2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Using `rbindlist` to bind the datasets, group by 'LobsterID' and subset the rows using the logical condition based on the number of unique elements in 'Sampler' i.e. equal to 2.

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(list(sampler1, sampler2))[, if(uniqueN(Sampler)==2) .SD , by = LobsterID]
```